# Tags HTML permitidas no SOPT

Tags: suporte, formatação, comentários

Escrevi um comentário para uma das perguntas e durante a edição quis utilizar uma tag HTML de formatação para adicinar o texto sobrescrito (tag `<sub>`), mas ao enviar o comentário, a tag não foi reconhecida como válida, exibindo o texto literal.

Encontrei esta pergunta [Quais tags HTML são permitidas (em inglês)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) no meta do SO. A resposta afirma a tag que eu utilizei é válida,  segura e permitida, mas não exibiu o resultado que eu esperava.

O conjunto de tags HTML válidos no SO é o mesmo daqui?

Comment: Acho que comentários não suportam HTML. <b>Viu?</b>

Comment: Parece que é isso... usei as tags <sup></sup>. Por descuido meu, nem percebi que elas não apareceram na pergunta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pergunta que você linkou diz respeito a tags HTML em *posts*, ou seja, perguntas e respostas. **[Comentários não suportam tags, somente um subconjunto do markdown](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help/#comment-formatting)**.

Para referência, eis as tags suportadas em perguntas e respostas:

```
<a>              - hyperlink.
<b>              - negrito, use somente em último caso; prefira <h1>-<h3>, <em> e <strong>.
<blockquote>     - seção originária de outra fonte.
<code>           - trecho de código.
<del>            - delete, utilize para indicar alterações/remoções.
<dd>             - um item de uma lista de descrição <dl>.
<dl>             - lista de descrição.
<dt>             - nome de um item numa lista de descrição <dl>.
<em>             - ênfase.
<h1>, <h2>, <h3> - cabeçalhos.
<i>              - itálico.
<img>            - tag de imagem.
<kbd>            - identifica entrada via teclado.
<li>             - item de uma lista ordenada <ol> ou lista sem ordem <ul>.
<ol>             - lista ordenada.
<p>              - parágrafo.
<pre>            - exibido com fonte de largura fixa e quebras de linha preservadas.
<s>              - tachado.
<sup>            - texto sobrescrito fica 1/2 caractere acima da linha de base;
                   utilizar para notas de roadapé e outros.
<sub>            - texto subescrito fica 1/2 caractere abaixo da linha de base;
<strong>         - texto importante.
<strike>         - em desuso, utilizar <del>.
<ul>             - lista sem ordem.
<br>             - quebra de linha.
<hr>             - denota mudança de tema, geralmente exibida como linha horizontal.
```

<sup>Fonte: [resposta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/167534) a [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)</sup>